# I'm trying to better understand the use of for

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between 2 sentences.
 1-)if it was not for the help of local people 
2-) )if it was not the help of local people 
But whatever their grumble **if it was not for the help of local people** even more of the settlers would have died.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two *phrases* is that (1) is correct and (2) is not.

The phrase *If it was not for X* has the meaning *If X were not available.* Your sentence is referring to the past, so it would be better to use *if it **had not been** for the help of local people...*